# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '60' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I encounter a problem, indeed, I want a function facing an update or an insert according to the existence or not.

I read in the Symfony documentation this:
Whether you're creating or updating objects, the workflow is always the same: Doctrine is smart enough to know if it should INSERT or UPDATE your entity.

My repository :

```
public function refreshAllArticle()
{
    $articlesActualise = $this->ApiManager->getAllArticles();

    $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();

    foreach ($articlesActualise as $articleActualise) {


        $article = new Articles();

        $article->setId($articleActualise['id']);

        $article->setDateCreation($articleActualise['date_creation']);
        $article->setDateModification($articleActualise['date_modification']);
        $article->setTitre($articleActualise['titre']);
        $article->setContent($articleActualise['content']);
        $article->setDescription($articleActualise['description']);

        $entityManager->persist($article);

        $entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

My entity :

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ArticlesRepository::class)]
class Articles
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'date')]
    private $date_creation;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'date', nullable: true)]
    private $date_modification;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private $titre;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'text', nullable: true)]
    private $content;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'text', nullable: true)]
    private $description;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'text', nullable: true)]
    private $header;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'text', nullable: true)]
    private $script;
```

And my controller :

```
#[Route('/refreshArticles', name: 'refreshArticles')]
public function refreshArticle(): RedirectResponse
{
    $this->doctrine->getRepository(Articles::class)->refreshAllArticle();
    return $this->redirectToRoute('articles');

}
```

The insertion works perfectly, but if I want to call this function again to make an update I get this error:
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '60' for key 'PRIMARY'

PS : For information, my ID is not in auto-increment because I want to be able to insert my own values

Could you help me thanks :)

Comment: It's actually a bit unusual to explicitly set id's but it can work.  As far as refreshing goes you need to fetch any existing entity then update the columns and flush.  If an entity for a given id does not exist then you would create a new one.  And off-topic but save your future self some agony and rename Articles to Article.

Comment: Ok I understand, maybe you can show me how to do it, because I don't know how to manifest an UPDATE, since it's similar to insert... And no worries, I rename my entity: )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine does not know out of the box whether an entity with a given idenfitier already exists or not. It can determine what it should do with an entity (e.g. if you persist twice in the same execution it will only insert once, if you fetch an entity, update and persist it it will update the entity).

However you're currently always *creating* a new entity from the existing data and persisting it. Instead you should first check whether or not an entity with the given id already exists. I am assuming that this repository class extends the `Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository` class which provides a "find" function to get an entity by id) so here is an example:

```php
public function refreshAllArticle()
{
    $articlesActualise = $this->ApiManager->getAllArticles();

    $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();

    foreach ($articlesActualise as $articleActualise) {
        // Fetch existing article object
        $articleToUpdate = $this->find($articleActualise['id']);
        if ($articleToUpdate === null) {
            // Article does not exist so we need to create a new object
            $articleToUpdate = new Articles();
        }

        // Update logic goes here using setters on $articleToUpdate 
        // Just like you previously already did

        $entityManager->persist($articleActualise);

        $entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

This way you will first check if the entity for the id already exists and update that one instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Ok but when I try to put my parameters with the setters, I have to create an object... and it comes back to what I did above?

Comment: Gotcha, I missunderstood what `$this->ApiManager->getAllArticles()` was returning. I adjusted my answer accordingly